# Execute Logstash via exec PHP

Tags: php, logstash

I use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) to play with Logs. I create the config file :

```
input {
  ...
}

filter {
  ...
}

output {
  ...
}
```

And I run the command line :

```
bin/logstash -f myfile.conf
```

Everything works perfectly, and I get the result I want.

The main problem that I want Execute the command via exec PHP :

```
exec('bin/logstash -f myfile.conf');
```

The command seems not working, why ?

Comment: How do you know it is not working?

Comment: I Use for output ElasticSearch

Comment: Are you logging any errors? Have you checked the error logs for PHP CLI?

Comment: No, no errors, I think the problem with exec

Comment: I doubt there is an issue with exec. Can you show the rest of your PHP?

Comment: There is no rest of php code, the php file just have one file with exec

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: What kind of input do you have in your Logstash configuration?

Comment: nginx file.
@JayBlanchard nothing happened

Comment: Without error logging we're probably not going to be able to solve here. My guess would be that PHP does not have permission to run the script using exec.

Comment: Ok. I think I will use bin file, and execute it via PHP

Comment: But seriously, why would you want to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code must be run as **root** user. I bet it is run as www-data which is standard setup due to security reasons.